# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView not working, the child recyclerview scrolls internally ,The View above recyclerView Doesn't scroll at all

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView is not working; the child recyclerview scrolls internally while the View above recyclerView doesn't scroll at all.

The otherEvents recycler view which is a vertical recycler view doesn't scroll If i use `recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`. The recyclerview scrolls internally if I don't use the above code.

I have already tried all answers on Stack Overflow. Nothing works. Please help.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#525252"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#525252"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pad_15dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/livethenight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="#525252"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="101 Upcoming Events \u0026 Parties in Bangalore "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/experienceText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#525252"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Book tickets or get on guestlist for amazing nightlife experiences"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/livethenight" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tendingEvents"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#525252"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/heart"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Featured Events"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/experienceText" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/featured_Banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#525252"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tendingEvents" />

            <cz.intik.overflowindicator.OverflowPagerIndicator
                android:id="@+id/view_pager_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/pad_30dp"
                android:background="#525252"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/featured_Banner" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/space"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_pager_indicator" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/categoy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/pad_5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_pager_indicator" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/Experience_date"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/categoy"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/pad_5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_10dp"
                    android:text="When do you want to experience?"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />



            </RelativeLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/date_week_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Experience_date" />




            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/djLayout"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_week_recycler"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/pad_5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_10dp"
                    android:text="Ape's Choice"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/see_all"
                    android:textColor="#ff6666"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"

                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/apesChoiceRecycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/djLayout" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/otherEvents"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/apesChoiceRecycler" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java code:

```
moreEventsAdapter=new MoreEventsAdapter(allEvents);
        layoutManager34= new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        otherEvents.setLayoutManager(layoutManager34);
        otherEvents.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        otherEvents.setAdapter(moreEventsAdapter)

;
```

Comment: try recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);                                                               I also met this problem. And upgrade to 26.1.0 fix it.

Comment: tried that.. recyclerView stops scrolling after that